# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -l

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to follow the instructions on https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html to create kivy android applications. I installed Kivy Buildozer VM and was following instructions on the Readme file. Created the buildozer.spec file using `buildozer init` command but `buildozer android debug`is failing with following output

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /media/sf_virtual_box/organizer/2nd_vid_tute/tut1_vid4/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

PYTHON-FOR-ANDROID ERROR! SEE BELOW FOR SOLUTION:

You are trying to run an old version of python-for-android via
distribute.sh. However, python-for-android has been rewritten and no
longer supports the distribute.sh interface.

If you are using buildozer, you should:
- upgrade buildozer to the latest version (at least 0.30)
- delete the .buildozer folder in your app directory (the same directory that has your buildozer.spec)
- run buildozer again as normal

If you are not using buildozer, see
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/README.md for
instructions on using the new python-for-android
toolchain. Alternatively, you can get the old toolchain from the
'old_toolchain' branch at
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/old_toolchain .

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -l
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Then I tried to update using `buildozer android update`  But fails giving the following output

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git clean -dxf'
# Cwd /media/sf_virtual_box/organizer/2nd_vid_tute/tut1_vid4/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
# Run 'git pull origin master'
# Cwd /media/sf_virtual_box/organizer/2nd_vid_tute/tut1_vid4/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
From https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /media/sf_virtual_box/organizer/2nd_vid_tute/tut1_vid4/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

PYTHON-FOR-ANDROID ERROR! SEE BELOW FOR SOLUTION:

You are trying to run an old version of python-for-android via
distribute.sh. However, python-for-android has been rewritten and no
longer supports the distribute.sh interface.

If you are using buildozer, you should:
- upgrade buildozer to the latest version (at least 0.30)
- delete the .buildozer folder in your app directory (the same directory that has your buildozer.spec)
- run buildozer again as normal

If you are not using buildozer, see
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/README.md for
instructions on using the new python-for-android
toolchain. Alternatively, you can get the old toolchain from the
'old_toolchain' branch at
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/old_toolchain .

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -l
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `However, python-for-android has been rewritten and no
longer supports the distribute.sh interface` you should not use `distribute.sh` and run `buildozer` as normal

Comment: hi mic4ael, can you please let me know how to run buildozer as normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/distribute.sh) the distribute.sh file is not supposed to be used anymore. [Here](http://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) you have a guide how to use `buildozer` directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are gettting this error in the Kivy Android Build Image you should update buildozer like this:

1.type

```
sudo pip install -U buildozer
```

2. delete the .buildozer folder in your app folder

The sudo password for this image is kivy123

3. type

   ```
       buildozer -v android debug
   ```

   to see what happens during compilation.